# On Dispatcher servlet file name

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

Can anyone explain why we are giving the file name as 
`<servlet-name> something </servlet-name>` - servlet.xml for dispatcher servlet in spring mvc?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, it's a placeholder name for a servlet. A webapp can have multiple dispatchers (but usually just one). I wrote this article: http://www.baeldung.com/register-servlet - it's mostly programmatic registration but the examples cover different registration topics. The default servlet-name is "dispatcher".